# virtualbox on os x lags when not active

Tags: ubuntu, networking, osx, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I am running ubuntu server as guest inside virtualbox on os x 10.10.x host

While the system works, it lags whenever the virtualbox window is not the active app.

E.g. I log into ubuntu from terminal over SSH. Then I do something inside chrome and go back to terminal. Start typing and nothing happens. I have to wait about 5-10s or simply to click on the virtualbox window. Then everything works perfectly.

The virtual machine is connected over virtual network vbox0.

Does anybody have an idea how to fix this. Have not found anything despite searching on google and stack. Thank you in advance, for any help!

**Seems also to be a network problem. Here is the ping from terminal. You can see when the app is active and when not. As soon as I touch the virtualbox window, response time gets to 0.x seconds.**

[image: ping from host to guest]

Comment: How much RAM did you tell virtualbox to use for the ubuntu virtual machine? How much RAM does the Mac have?

Comment: 16gig ram host; 8gig guest

Answer (score 0):

The guest did have 4 Cores selected from 4 marked as green with 90% processing power on a dual core chip. Changed it to 2 cores and now it works. Thank you Marc for your hint with the RAM.

Comment: Seems like the problem still persits. Once I change to other apps and return to terminal after it, I have to touch the virtualbox window before the machine gets responsive again. Any ideas?